# synchronized block showing weird results

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am trying to run a simple multi-threaded program in java that uses a `synchronized` block inside a non-static method.I have a class `TestThread` which has a field `string` which is a `StringBuffer` variable. I have created two threads `one` and `two` and each of their `string` variables initialized to `StringBuffer` `b` which contains the value `A` . The first thread that goes to running state has to display the value `A` hundred times and after that increment it by one so that the next thread running will display the incremented value `B` hundred times too.I have used the current object denoted by `this` inside the `synchronized`. But unfortunately I am not getting the expected output. The first thread is displaying `A` more than hundred times and second thread is displaying `B` less than 100. And each time I run it, I am getting different outputs.So I think that the mutual exclusion is not achieved. What I am doing wrong here?

```
    public class TestThread extends Thread{

        StringBuffer string;
        public void run(){
            synchronized(this){
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                    System.out.print(this);
                }
                System.out.println();
                string.setCharAt(0,(char)(string.charAt(0)+1));
            }
        }

        public TestThread(StringBuffer string){
            this.string=string;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return string.toString();
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            StringBuffer b=new StringBuffer("A");
            TestThread one=new TestThread(b);
            TestThread two=new TestThread(b);
            one.start();
            two.start();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than 10 years ago.

Comment: Also don't extend Thread unless you like really obscure bugs to appear in your code.  You should implement Runnable and pass this to a `new Thread`

Comment: When you use `synchronized` the choice of object to lock on matters, you need to lock on the same object as the other thread, the obvious choice being the object you want to modify e.g. the `String`

Comment: @PeterLawrey It works fine if I use the StringBuffer object. I am doing it as a programming exercise and did not understand why using 'this' does not work

Comment: @hermit - `this` is different for different threads. Got it?

Comment: Never the less using StringBuffer is a bad idea, too many people think it's thread safe when it is almost impossible to use it correctly that way.

Comment: @TheLostMind But (this.getClass()) for all the threads gives the 'TestThread' class

Comment: @PeterLawrey ok I will use StringBuilder instead in future

Comment: In this case you could just use a `char[]` since it seems the only use you have for it is to be able to mutate it.

Comment: @hermit - just print `this` and see the value after `@`. They will be different :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I am sorry. I confused the same class for same instance.Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @hermit - No problemo.. I've  been there:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are locking on the *current object* i.e, `this`. Thus you are locking on 2 *different objects*. Use a common lock and then try the same example.

`synchronized(this)` ==> `synchronized(someGlobalObject)`

Comment: ... like the global object the thread is modifying ie `string`

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I would prefer a different one.. Perhaps an Object.. But you are right.. :)

Comment: but when i checked the class 'this' belonged to , for all the threads it was TestThread class. But it works if i use 'string'.

Comment: @hermit - the lock is on a specific *instance* of a class, not on the whole class. `this` is the current *instance* of `TestThread` - either the instance you created in `one` or the one you placed in `two`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic o I got it.Thanks